# Import module from other directory in Wing Ide

Tags: python, import, wing-ide

In module MainClass.py which is in c:\MyProject\ModelClasses I'm
trying import module MainHelper.py from c:\MyProject\Helpers

```
from Helpers.MainHelper import MainHelper

x=MainHelper()
```

and I get error

```
ImportError: No module named Helpers.MainHelper
```

In WIng IDe I've added path c:\MyProject\Helpers Project->ProjectProperties\PythonPath

I'm using windows xp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `c:\MyProject\Helpers` is in `PYTHONPATH`, you should write

```
from MainHelper import MainHelper
```

in the MainClass.py module.

If you want to treat the `Helpers` directory as a package, do the following:

- `PYTHONPATH` should be `c:\MyProject`
- The `Helpers` directory should have a (possibly empty) `__init__.py` file in it.

You would then use import statements like:

```
import Helpers.MainHelper
from Helpers.MainHelper import MainHelper
from Helpers import MainHelper
```

Documentation links:

- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html
- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages